# how do i add a login menu to superfish menu module?

Tags: routes, users, navigation

I thought i would be able to add the default User Login menu to a Superfish block, but it doesn't appear in the drop down list to be able to select when configuring the Superfish block.

Can anyone advise how to create a login menu for superfish that disappears when users are logged in. I have my Main Menu in Superfish 1 block, and my User Menu (contains logout) in my Superfish 2 block (works perfectly as only appears when logged in), and wanted a Superfish 3  for User Login (to only appear when logged out).

Perhaps there is an easier way to do this, so open to suggestions?

Comment: i have added a menu item to User Menu for Login (/user/login), this works fine when Im logged out as just 'Member Login' appears, but when logged in, the Member Login item is still visible in the menu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merely added an extra option to my main menu called 'Member Login' path user/login , then once you login this automatically disappears and I get my User Menu appear in my Superfish2 block with has my logout and other options that are only permitted by authenticated users. Thanks for advise on other menus.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SuperFish, you should consider using:

#### [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu)

> TB Mega Menu allows you to create a mega menu with an innovative
> back-end user interface and synchronized with Drupal core menu.
>
> - Synchronized with Drupal core menu, auto updated if there’s any change with - -  - Drupal core menu
> - Bootstrap framework
> - Responsive ready
> - Multiple built-in styles designed with years of theming experience
> - Visual and friendly user interface - what you see is what you get
> - Custom style for each element of your mega menu, just input extra css class name
> - Multiple built-in CSS3 animated effects
> - Work independently with themes

Speaking from experience, I know you can add the login block to TB Mega Menu

Here is a [Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnuhbFwsJ3M)